# New user email notification not being sent

Tags: users, emails

This is my first day using Drupal, and I apologize in advance for such a basic question.  I am using Drupal 7.26 with no modules installed and when I try to sign up new users the e-mail notification is not being sent.  I tried signing up with two different e-mail addresses and checked the spam folder in each account.  I also tried to find an answer on the internet but I'm not having much luck.  Can anyone provide some suggestions on how I might troubleshoot this issue?  I've been to my Administration>Account Settings and Administration>Site Information but I'm not seeing anything that looks obviously amiss.

Comment: Does your server support smtp ?

Comment: I'm actually not sure.  I read some posts discussing smtp and reviewing logs, but I couldn't find sufficient information to enable me to understand well enough.  Can you let me know how I can check whether my server supports smtp?  I am using a dreamhosters account.  Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if people who vote down a question (like has happened to mine) would let the person who posted the question know why the question is being voted down.

Comment: Try http://drupalconnect.com/blog/how-debug-drupal-not-sending-email

Comment: Thank you, Anil!  I will take a look.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install and use the SMTP module: https://drupal.org/project/smtp - Period. Nothing comes close to using SMTP and you'll avoid current and future headaches. Details are below. Good luck!

**Why sending via the server is bad:**

The post recommended by Anil Sagar is good. However, based on my expertise with web hosts, especially DreamHost, you want to avoid at all costs sending emails from your server.

By default, Drupal sends email via the server it's residing on. That server might not have email configured. That server might have email configured now, not properly configured in the future. That server might get spam listed in the future. In summary, a lot of things might happen that leave you without email sending capabilities, and most probably you will not be notified of the issue.

Also, you're lucky that your email is "not working" as, in most cases, some emails via the server will be sent, others will not, which is even worse as you'll not even know you have a problem to fix.

**Why sending via SMTP rocks:**

When you send via SMTP, you're relying on an external dedicated mail server. Choose a solid mail server provider (Gmail, Yahoo, Zoho, etc) and you'll be on the safe side. They handle maintenance and everything for you and all you have to worry about is the first step which is setting up and installing the SMTP module.

**Note about SMTP sending limits:**

If you're sending a large number of emails, most good email providers will have a daily limit that you'll reach and they'll stop sending your emails. This is a way for them to fight spam. For Gmail, I think the daily limit is 250 emails, which is plenty for most needs. If you have larger volumes, you might want to buy a paid SMTP account with a large limit or consider something like: http://www.mandrill.com/ - You can send up to 12,000 per month for free. They also have a Drupal integration module: https://drupal.org/project/mandrill

And if you're sending a large number of emails via your own server, you're ending up on a spam list from day one and your emails will soon not even reach junk mail.

Comment: Mario - Thank you for your answer which was very useful.  I was unaware of this module until I read your answer.  Are there any disadvantages to using the SMTP Module in connection with a mail server provider (even if only minor disadvantages or risks -- that way I will be better informed)?  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Definitely there's risk especially if you don't choose a good mail provider, they might go down or might change their business model and stop providing email; usually to charge a fee. However, compared to sending via your own server, this is really nothing. I also added a note on limits in the answer, please read it. Weclome to StackExchange, create a username please and if this answers your question please make it accepted. Good luck.

Comment: Mario - Thank you!  The limit information was very useful.

Comment: Good luck. Cheers.